# Не переведены строки для функционала по правке меток вопроса

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, вопросы

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Строка в transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/152600949?q=key%3Abb16b0f00a343b8b320c2f9711acc771) (ключ: bb16b0f00a343b8b320c2f9711acc771).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Строка в transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/152600951?q=key%3A70785214f7297474a487a2d95363594b) (ключ:  70785214f7297474a487a2d95363594b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переводы применены и по синхронизации добавятся на сайт.

Comment: Какие переводы? Где сами фразы?

Comment: @alexolut ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯