# Слетел перевод Edit tags

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Собственно, скриншот:

[image: скриншот]

Интересно, что тултип остался на русском.

Comment: Странно. Дизайн откатился у этой панельки https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7857/15479 Я недавно по ней репортил косяки перевода, сейчас она иначе выглядит.

Comment: Там была кнопка на русском с тултипом на английском, а теперь наоборот. Своп багов)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевел строку с ключом `976fa4218a7614defe8632897bd0d160` как:

> Править метки

Перевод слетел, так как изменился регистр буквы. Было со строчной, стало с прописной. Где-то ещё есть (или был) вариант с двумя прописными.

Появится на сайте после череды обновлений.

Comment: Что-то по-прежнему не работает, хотя уже `rev 2018.9.17.31574`

Comment: @Qwertiy возможно КМ не читает Мету